# raspberry pi 3 wireless adaptor not detected

Tags: pi-3, wireless, wireless-adapter

Hi I bought raspberry pi 3 model B. I'm using raspbian and 16gb sdcard. when I boot up raspberry pi for first time, bluetooth was activated but wireless not! I'm using 1.5A power supply and for next time that I boot up my raspberry pi bluetooth doesnt work too !

please help me, is there the problem for power supply? is the wireless or bluetooth currepted?

Comment: It does not sound like a power issue if the WiFi adapter is the only device you plugged in to the USB port.

Comment: raspberry pi 3 have internal wireless and bluetooth card. I'm using just keyboard and mouse on usb ports

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what you mean by "does not work".  E.g., many people have problems getting a wifi adapter to do what they want, but this doesn't mean it doesn't work.  Basic evidence for it not working would be, e.g., if `ip link` output did not list it as an interface.